# How to load test Sign Up API using Jmeter for 100 users where mobile number & email are unique

Tags: performance, api, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have to perform load test on a Sign UP API using Jmeter. 
Sign Up asks for:

1. valid cell # where system sends SMS code for verfication
2. Valid Email address where user receives a link for verification

Can any one help for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It might be tricky, however you can consider a 3rd-party application like [Spikko](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spikko.mobile&hl=en) or [2nr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.rs.sip.softphone&hl=en) and use mobile automation framework like [Appium](http://appium.io/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) in order to get SMS text from the mobile application. If you don't have a real phone you can use an emulator like [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/#gref) or [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)
2. For email it is way easier, JMeter comes with [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) so you can fetch an email from any real box and extract confirmation URL from there, check out [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733729-How-to-Create-a-JMeter-Script-to-Check-Email-During-Registration-AND-Grab-the-Confirmation-URL) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) and get from DB the code/link sent.

But if it's not possible, for email you can concatenate to same gmail `+${UUID()}`. Gmail at least [support](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) sending to same mail if have different suffix:

> Here are two different ways you can modify your Gmail address and still get your mail:
>
> Append a plus ("+") sign and any combination of words or numbers after your email address. For example, if your name was hikingfan@gmail.com, you could send mail to hikingfan+friends@gmail.com or hikingfan+mailinglists@gmail.com.